# How to add a catch-all wildcard to hook_menu?

Tags: 7, navigation

I want a url structure like so:

```
https://example.com/bob
```

which loads a custom page for the user bob. This is what I'm trying:

```
function mymodule_storefront_menu() {

    $items = array();

    // Wildcard catch for user's storefront
    $items['%'] = array(
      'title'           => 'User custom page',
      'type'            => MENU_CALLBACK,
      'page callback'   => 'mymodule_load_user_page',
      'page arguments'  => array(0),
      'access callback' => TRUE,
    );

    return $items;
}

function mymodule_load_user_page($user) {
    echo $user;
}
```

However, I'm getting a server 404 and drupal is logging a 'page not found' message the the dblog. Any ideas?

Edit:

I am able to get this to work:

```
$items['u/%'] = array(...);
```

but would prefer the plain wildcard to work, if possible.

Comment: "Note that wildcards may not be used as the first component." -- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x) says it in the first wildcard example it provides. (Emphasis is mine.)

> ### Wildcards in Paths
>
> #### Simple Wildcards
>
> Wildcards within paths also work with integer substitution. For example, your module could register path 'my-module/%/edit':
>
> ```
>   $items['my-module/%/edit'] = array(
>     'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_edit',
>     'page arguments' => array(1),
>   );
> ```
>
> When path 'my-module/foo/edit' is requested, integer 1 will be replaced with 'foo' and passed to the callback function. **Note that wildcards may not be used as the first component.**

The reason of this is pretty easy to understand: A wildcard as first component would be a catch-up for every Drupal route.
It would also conflict with the routes every Drupal module defines. This is also the reason why Drupal core uses node/%node for nodes, and user/%user for user accounts: Despite the wildcards being qualified, Drupal would not understand if a URI like 1 is referring to a node or a user account.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. Despite being told in another comment this was the case, I was still having trouble finding it on the page. My hope was that drupal would know to execute the wildcard last, if all other rules fail, but you make a good point about conflict. Seems allowing that would interfere with other modules that wanted to do a catch-all.

Answer (score 2):

Wildcards may not be used as the first component of a route path.

Comment: You are better to add the source as you did in comment.